# creating hidden files using .NET

Tags: .net, file-io, file-properties

How can I create or mark a file as hidden using .NET?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [File.SetAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx).  "Hidden" is just one of many available attributes.

Comment: ThanX bro..!! one of other site gave me wrong information that- dotnet can-not hide a file.

Answer (score 12):

You set the `hidden` attribute of the file.

There are several ways of doing so - with [`File.SetAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx) or [`FileInfo.Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes.aspx), you simply set the [`FileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) enumeration flag to hidden:

```
string path = @"c:\myfile.txt";
File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are referring to setting the file attribute to hidden in the file system.
Please take a look at this [link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-attributes/)

Answer (score 2):

If it's an existing file, i.e. not one you've just created, don't just:

```
File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

or certain other attributes it may have will be lost, so rather you should:

```
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
```